# Python3 ошибка в модуле Yadisk

Tags: python-3.x

У меня имеется код, который архивирует файлы и отправляет их на яндекс диск, но к сожалению, там появляется ошибка:

```
file_name = "FlashUSB"
 
def flashsend(name):   
    try:
        shutil.make_archive(file_name, 'zip', name)
        y.upload(f"{file_name}.zip", f"/{file_name}.zip") # ошибка
    except Exception as e:
        return print(e)
 
#Output: Ресурс "/FlashUSB.zip" уже существует. (Resource "/FlashUSB.zip" already exists. / DiskResourceAlreadyExistsError)
```

Не смотря на ошибку, архив появляется на яндекс диске, но все равно, очень интересно в чем проблема.
(Перед запуском скрипта я полностью чищу диск, поэтому этого ресурса там быть не должно.)

Comment: y.upload(f"{file_name}.zip", f"/{file_name}.zip") что то мне эта строчка не нравиться.

Comment: Там вот такой синтаксис: "y.upload("file_to_upload.txt", "/destination.txt")"